# How to create an external list from an ECT using powershell

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I have an External Content Type in my Metadata store and I want to create an external list using that ECT, using Powershell script.

I tried to use `$Web.Lists.Add()` with SiteTemplate = "External List" but it doesn't seem to work.

There was another example online by creating a ListDatasource object, but that gives me error

> "IMethodInstance could not be found using criteria..." and a
>   MetadataObjectNotFoundException

, although the Object is there.

Does anyone have any pointers to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Following link might help.

[Auto Create External Lists for Each ECTs contained within a specific BCS model](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/82437789-f294-4bcd-8210-a1ba0e081f82/)

Can't use `"External List"` as SiteTemplate since you have to specify the BDC Model's properties.